# Como utilizar glyphicons

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, quiero usar los iconos glyphicons en mi proyecto.
Para ello, tengo este código:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<?php
    $tipos=App\Tipo::all();
?>

<li style="width: 205px; position: relative; left: 130px;" class="nav-item dropdown btn-secondary">
    <a id="navbarDropdown"
        class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
        href="#" role="button"
        data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="false"
        style="color:white;" 
    ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Artículos {{$mensaje}}<span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        @foreach($tipos as $tipo)
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('/articulo_filtrar/'.$tipo->id) }}">Filtrar por {{$tipo->nombre}}</a>
        @endforeach
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('/') }}">Ver todas las noticias</a>
    </div>
</li>
<br>
```

Lo que tengo en el `<link>` del comienzo habilita el uso de estos iconos, pero tengo un problema:
Así es como se ve la pagina si no lo pongo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así si lo pongo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Algunas letras se vuelven más pequeñas al incluir esta etiqueta!
¿Como evito esto?
Como utilizo bootstrap 4, parece ser que ya no tengo acceso a glyphicon. ¿Como lo habilito sin necesidad de volver a la versión 3 de bootstrap, como estoy haciendo?
Tambien he intentado esto para que se vea la imagen:

```
<img src=&#xe138;>
```

Pero la imagen no se ve.

Comment: No será por culpa del responsive style de bootstrap?

Comment: @Raulitus ¿Y como arreglo mi problema?

Comment: Jugando con el css dependiendo de las dimensiones que te cargue uno u otro. Aunque esto es más bien "chapucero"

Comment: Ese cdn tiene estilos que afectan al tamaño de la tipografia, pon los estilos de bootstrap4 despues de los de glyphicons para que los sobreescriban

Comment: @blonfu Lo que dices es interesante. ¿Como lo logro?

Comment: Has dicho que usas bootstrap 4. Solo tienes que poner el `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">` antes de cargar los demas estilos que tengas